# Error VBA 9 Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with 3 tabs.

Second tab (Sheet2) is with data from Oracle DB.

I created a pivot table in Sheet3 with data from Sheet2.

I want the Pivot Table to update automatically when the data changes.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh  
End Sub
```

PivotTable4 is the name of the PivotTable.

After some minutes I got the error:

> Run-time error '9' : Subscript out of range.

Comment: Is this the only macro code you're running, or is there more? Does it give the error after running successfully for a few minutes, or does a single run take several minutes to fail?

Comment: I noticed that I get this error when I run 2 macro codes for 2 different excels .

Comment: When I erase one macro code  the other macro works .

Comment: Sounds to me like `Sheet3` and/or `PivotTable4` only exist in one of your workbooks, and your code is trying to use those names in a context where they don't exist. Try specifying the workbook in the call to `PivotCache.Refresh`. Alternatively, the problem is unrelated to the code you've posted and is being caused by the other macro in the other workbook.

Comment: These 2 workbooks are from 2 different charts from power point . How can I specify the workbook in the code ?

Comment: `Workbooks(workbookName).Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh `

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now it works :)

Comment: No problem - posted as an answer, feel free to accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with multiple workbooks, you'll get a "Subscript out of range" error if your code looks for an object with a particular name in one workbook when in fact it's in the other. Therefore, if you're going to have multiple workbooks open, it's always a good idea to qualify the one in which you want the code to be executed, for example:

```
Workbooks("MyWorkbook").Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("Pi‌​votTable4").PivotCac‌​he.Refresh
```